# How to migrate new web design to an existing website?

Tags: migration, wordpress.com-hosting, duplicates, clone-site

Can someone help me, I have duplicator pro but i don't think it's quite what i need to perform the tasks I am looking to do ?

I have a live website, fully functioning, however, it was a bit outdated in this example we will call this website "**website1.com**" .

I have then used a completely new domain and hosting package and re-designed a brand new website using elementor pro which in this example we will call "**website2.com**".

The issue is, I would like to transfer all my new designed pages, plugins and images from my new website2.com to website1.com.

However, I would like to keep all my old pages, design and plugins on website1.com and not overwrite or delete them.

Can someone tell me how I can achieve this by transferring website2.com to website1.com ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**1st step:** clear yourself about how you want to retain the existing content.

*For example:* a contact page on website1.com might be having `/contact/` permalink and on **website2.com** the permalink could be same. So, when you migrate `/contact/` from **website2** to **website1**, what do you want WP to do if not overwrite then, it changes/appends the new content URLs to `/contact-2/` etc. But in this case, your existing internal links will break and you will need to update the links everywhere.

Either start clean by downloading/exporting all the data (files + sql) if you just need a backup. OR get ready for permalink update hassle since you want both versions so, you'll have /contact/ and /new-contact/ like pages.

**2nd step:** considering you're clear how to retain and know the consequences regarding permalink changes.

- Install new design dependencies (plugins/theme or tools that you used for a new design) on **website1.com** such as Elementor and probably its related extensions.
- Configure the dependencies i-e: Set the Elementor/others settings as you set on **website2.com** to make sure that when you import newly designed pages, they get the same effects.
- Export pages, posts, or other designed pages from **website2.com** using Wordpress Export option available at WP Dashboard > Settings > Export
- Import them on **website1.com** using WP Dashboard > Settings > Import
- Flush permalinks for once from Settings > Permalinks > Click 'Save Permalinks'
- Verify the new style/design or new page from the frontend.